# replacing special characters in SQL 2000

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, replace

how can I replace special characters in my data files (special characters such as bullet points, percent sign, hyphen etc) ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you replacing them with SQL or in a file that will be loaded into a database?

Comment: I am writing a stored proc that will replace these characters;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [T-SQL REPLACE](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ra-rz_6.htm):

```
REPLACE(FieldWithStars,'*','STAR')
```

For more than one substitution you could use cascading REPLACE statements.

No clue though about bullet points - but you should be able to replace anything looking for the right escape sequence for that particular character.

Comment: Be aware of the cascading stops at 32. If there are more characters to be replaced you should programm a loop an go thru...

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but it might be helpful when replacements involve a large number of tokens and/or their management must dealt outside of the script (i.e. from an UI). Also, mixing data (search/replacement tokens are hardcoded) with logic is not recommended.

Since [aggregate replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844481/aggregate-replace-in-sql-server) do not work (`UPDATE` does a single scan through the records), I have used a function to actually perform the aggregate updates for each string). I expect a lower performance than the classic solution, but it has the advantages mentioned above:

```
-- function to perform the replacements
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceFromTable (@s NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret NVARCHAR(4000) = @s

    SELECT @Ret = REPLACE(@Ret, R.SearchToken, R.ReplaceToken) 
    FROM dbo.Replacements R

    RETURN @Ret
END
GO

-- drop table dbo.Replacements
create table dbo.Replacements
(
    SearchToken NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    ReplaceToken NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
)
GO

insert into dbo.Replacements values (N'ó', N'o'), (N'ò', N'o'), (N'*', N' ')
GO

select * from dbo.Replacements
go

-- drop table dbo.Strings
create table dbo.Strings
(
    StringId INT NOT NULL,
    String NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
GO

insert into Strings values (1, N'Some dummy string'), (2, N'Nòthing really'), (3, N'Nóthing new under the Sun'), (4, N'**Earth**')
GO

select * from dbo.Strings
GO

UPDATE S
    SET S.String = dbo.ReplaceFromTable(S.String)
FROM dbo.Strings S
GO

select * from dbo.Strings
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 *****   Replacing special character by normal character eg ó by o,ê by e etc ***

  create proc dbo.specialcharacterreplacer

@tblname varchar(1000),
@column_name varchar(1000)

as
begin

--declare @obj VARCHAR(MAX),
--set @obj= 'select *from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '@tblname''
--exec @obj


declare @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
set @Sql = '
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ó'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ò'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ö'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ð'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ô'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''õ'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ó'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ó'''+ ', '+'''o'''+') 

update ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''×'''+ ', '+'''x'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''f'''+ ', '+'''f'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ò'''+ ', '+'''O'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ó'''+ ', '+'''O'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ô'''+ ', '+'''O'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Õ'''+ ', '+'''O'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ö'''+ ', '+'''O'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ñ'''+ ', '+'''n'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ñ'''+ ', '+'''N'''+')

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''è'''+ ', '+'''e'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''é'''+ ', '+'''e'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ê'''+ ', '+'''e'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ë'''+ ', '+'''e'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''È'''+ ', '+'''E'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''É'''+ ', '+'''E'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ê'''+ ', '+'''E'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ë'''+ ', '+'''E'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''á'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ã'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''â'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''à'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ä'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''å'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ª'''+ ', '+'''a'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''æ'''+ ', '+'''ae'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''À'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Á'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Â'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ã'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Å'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ä'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Æ'''+ ', '+'''A'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''æ'''+ ', '+'''AE'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ù'''+ ', '+'''u'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ú'''+ ', '+'''u'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''û'''+ ', '+'''u'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ü'''+ ', '+'''u'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''µ'''+ ', '+'''u'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ù'''+ ', '+'''U'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ú'''+ ', '+'''U'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Û'''+ ', '+'''U'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ü'''+ ', '+'''U'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ý'''+ ', '+'''Y'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ÿ'''+ ', '+'''Y'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ÿ'''+ ', '+'''y'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ý'''+ ', '+'''y'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''þ'''+ ', '+'''þ'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ç'''+ ', '+'''C'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ç'''+ ', '+'''c'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''œ'''+ ', '+'''ce'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Œ'''+ ', '+'''CE'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ì'''+ ', '+'''I'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Í'''+ ', '+'''I'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Î'''+ ', '+'''I'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ï'''+ ', '+'''I'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ì'''+ ', '+'''i'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''í'''+ ', '+'''i'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''î'''+ ', '+'''i'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ï'''+ ', '+'''i'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Ð'''+ ', '+'''D'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Þ'''+ ', '+'''D'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''ß'''+ ', '+'''B'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''Š'''+ ', '+'''S'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''š'''+ ', '+'''s'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''§'''+ ', '+'''S'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''½'''+ ', '+'''1/2'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''¼'''+ ', '+'''1/4'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''¾'''+ ', '+'''3/4'''+') 

UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''©'''+ ', '+'''Copyright '''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''®'''+ ', '+'''Registered trademark  '''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''‰'''+ ', '+'''%'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''¿'''+ ', '+'''?'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''º'''+ ', '+'''0'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''¹'''+ ', '+'''1'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''²'''+ ', '+'''2'''+') 
UPDATE ' + @tblname + ' SET ' + @column_name+ ' = REPLACE('+@column_name + ', ' + '''³'''+ ', '+'''3'''+') 

' -- add your special character here inside 
exec (@sql)
end

go
EXEC dbo.specialcharacterreplacer @tblname = 'insert tablename here', @column_name ='insert columnname  here'
```