# Replaces all occurrences of specified string values (which are stored in a table)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

For example, I want to replace all the occurrences of strings `r._from` in `t.s` with strings `r._to` in the following script.

```
with    r(_from, _to)
          as (select    'aaa', ''
              union all
              select    'bbb', ''
              union all
              select    'ccc', ''
              -- union all ..... and more
             ),
        t(s)
          as (select    'ABCaaaDEFbbb'
              union all
              select    '123aaabbb456'
             )
    select  t.s, .... -- replace aaa, bbb, ccc, ... with empty string ''
    from    t
```

should return

```
ABCDEF
123456
```

Assuming there is a powerful `replace` function which accept a table of mappings for replacement: `select replace(t.s, (select * from r)) from t`, this is what the question about. The code will be put in a view so I cannot update table or use temp table. Any xquery tricks? (Or fall back to dynamically create a view with indented `replace(replace(replace(.....` using xquery?)

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844481/aggregate-replace-in-sql-server

Comment: To my knowledge there is no built-in function for multiple replacements, so the ways to do this involve some type of iteration. That could take the form of a loop, recursive cte, cursor, or rolling your own function with one of those or even the `select @var = ...` method of recursion. One could also use any of those methods to create and run dynamic sql which outputs something like `replace(replace(replace(...`.

Comment: Also note that all of the normal solutions take place _in a sequence_, as in `select replace(replace('ab', 'a', 'b'), 'b', 'a')` returns `aa`.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own CLR:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class RegExBase
{
  [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
  public static string RegExReplace(string pattern, string matchString, string replacement)
  {
    Regex r1 = new Regex(pattern.TrimEnd(null));
    return Regex.replace(matchString.TrimEnd(null), replacement);
  }
};
```

And then use it:

```
with r(_from, _to) as (
    select    'aaa', ''
    union all
    select    'bbb', ''
    union all
    select    'ccc', ''
-- union all ..... and more
), t(s) as (
    select    'ABCaaaDEFbbb'
    union all
    select    '123aaabbb456'
)
select dbo.RegExReplace(r.from, t.s, r.to)
  from t, r
```

For more information read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx)

Comment: The cross join will duplicate the rows in `t`?